# Lightning Out VF page List view button

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am planning to create List button using lightning out, however I am not sure how to get the record Id dynamically from the VF page and pass it to Lightning Component.

```
<!-- This VF page hosts a Lightning Component. -->
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" recordSetVar="cons"
    showHeader="true"
    sidebar="false"
    standardStylesheets="false">

  <!-- Load Lightning dependencies -->
  <apex:includeLightning />

  <div class="slds">
    <!-- Target div for the Lightning component -->
    <div id="customObjectEdit"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var recordId = '0030v000001VfqhAAC';

    $Lightning.use("c:createLtgOutApp", function() {
      var attributes = {
        recordId: recordId
      };

      var targetElementId = 'customObjectEdit';

      $Lightning.createComponent('c:createLtgOut', attributes, targetElementId,
        function(cmp) {
          // At this point the component has been created and loaded
      });
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

This is the Opportunity list button which I am using it on Contact page. How do I get the Contact record Id dynamically here and pass it to Component attribute?

Is this the right approach or is there any other option do I have for related list button to prepopulate the values?

I guess, I have to write another extension controller to get the id of the record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out the way to get the id, I used the extension controller to get the id of the record.